# How do I do this in Lodash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have a array like structure from database results

```
var arr = [{name: 'a', age: 23}, {name: 'b', age: 24}, {name: 'c', age: 35}]
```

I want to create a new object with values as key and value like below:

```
var new_arra  = {a: 23, b: 24, c: 35}
```

How can I do this in lodash?

I tried the below method:

```
var result = _.forEach(results, function(index) {
    var result = _.map(index, function(value, prop) {
        return {prop: prop, value: value};
    });
});
```

Comment: Use map only!
const newResults results = results.map(item =>  ({
  [item.name]: item.age
}));

Comment: If you want to go from `Array` to `Object`, you need to use `reduce`.

Answer (score 3):

Using ES5 - iterate with [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with initial value of an empty object. On each iteration set the name as key, and the age as value.

```js
var arr = [{name: 'a', age: 23}, {name: 'b', age: 24}, {name: 'c', age: 35}];

var result = arr.reduce(function(obj, o) {
  obj[o.name] = o.age;

  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Using ES6 - Iterate with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) get the values using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and set using [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names). Combine all to a single object by using [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```js
const arr = [{name: 'a', age: 23}, {name: 'b', age: 24}, {name: 'c', age: 35}];

const result = Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(({ name, age }) => ({ [name]: age })));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with pure JS this way:

```js
var arr = [{
  name: 'a',
  age: 23
}, {
  name: 'b',
  age: 24
}, {
  name: 'c',
  age: 35
}]

var result = {};

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  result[item.name] = item.age
});

console.log(result);
```

Another way with `reduce`:

```js
var arr = [{
  name: 'a',
  age: 23
}, {
  name: 'b',
  age: 24
}, {
  name: 'c',
  age: 35
}];

var result = arr.reduce(function(store, item) {
  store[item.name] = item.age;
  return store;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hello Can you please check my question again I have just updated it for repsonse I need, It is just close and running, can you please help some more.

Comment: @Sachin Solanki I updated my answer and fix your question, you want to create a new object, not an array.

Comment: @Sachin Solanki Is it what you need?

Answer (score 1):

you need these two line only

```
let newData = {};
arr.map((item)=>newData[item.name]=item.age);

console.log(newData);
```

or you can also do it using lodash

```
 let newData = {};
 _.map(arr,(item)=>newData[item.name]=item.age);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's simple.

All you need to do is loop through each data and insert it into a new empty object.
Ex.

```
let new_arra = {};

_.each(arr, a => {
 new_arra[a.name] = a.age
});
```